# Necesito ayuda con una validación de Login en php. 5.6.25

Tags: php, login, wamp

Necesito ayuda con mi código en php ya que Ingreso el usuario y contraseña correspondiente para entrar y me redirige al mismo sitio de el principio al index.php, la conexión a la base de datos esta bien ya que estoy haciendo un sistema de inventario y perfectamente puedo hacer altas y bajas. el único problema que tengo es con el login.

Este es mi index.php.

```
 <?php 

 ?> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<center>
    <form method="POST" action="validar.php"> 
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Usuario">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"><br>
    <button type="submit">Iniciar Sesion</button>

    </form>
  </center>
  </div>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Este es mi validar.php.

```
 <?php  
include 'conex.php';
$usuario = $_POST['nombre'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
}
$query=("SELECT * FROM usuarios where Username='".$usuario."'");
echo var_dump($query);
$res = $con->query($query); 
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
if($row['Password'] == $pass){
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
header("Location: inicio.php");
}
else
{
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
}
} 
else
{
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Es sencillo, tu error es que nunca consultas si existe una sesión actual, solo te limitas a enviar a la pagina de logeo si no hay variables `$_POST`, para ser mas exacto en esta linea:

```
if (empty($usuario) || empty($pass)) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Ahora lo ideal es que tengas esto:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header("Location: inicio.php");
} else {
    // Sentencias...
}
```

- primero ejecutas `session_start` si no ha sido ejecutado nunca
  durante la petición.
- segundo redireccionas a tu pagina principal si el variable de sesión
  ha sido seteada, en caso contrario entonces es cuando entras a
  validar la información `$_POST`.

**Sugerencias**

1. Filtra los valores `$_POST` te expones a una inyección SQL por
   confiar en los valores enviado por el usuario.
2. `session_start` solo debe ejecutarse una vez por petición.

Comment: Me parece que deberias publicar la respuesta sin imagenes y colocando el codigo con el formato del sitio :)